# Getting the input of a confim box to C# variable in VS2005

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2005

How to get input from user using a confirm box in asp.net and store the input in a C# variable.
as whether it is a ok or cancel button. pls help me forward.

For Example i am using like this,
Response.Write("confirm('Testing FiileAlready existing Replace it?')");

instead i need the output of the confirm box in c# variable...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Your javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function ConfirmOnReplace() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?") == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
</script>
```

The ASP.NET button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return ConfirmOnReplace();" />
```

And the code-behind(YourPage.aspx.cs) file:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
    }

    void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If you are here, your javascript method returned true
        // TODO: Replace the file, or do what you want
    }
}
```